# How to avoid data loss using socket and pyqt with multithread

Tags: python, multithreading, sockets, pyqt5, qrunnable

I am continuously and simultaneously receiving images from multiple clients to a single server. I have used pyqt5 and QRunnable to achieve this. The code will accept the client connection pass it to a thread and start streaming image and data alongwith it in. However I observed that some images are not received/dropped in each thread. Here is my server side thread code which stream images from the clients:

```
class threading(QRunnable):
    def __init__(self,t1,t2,index,ttype,ptype,test):
        super(threading,self).__init__()

        self.t1=t1
        self.t2=t2

        self.ch=index
        self.ttype=ttype
        self.ptype=ptype
        self.test=test
        self.top1=""
        self.bot1=""
        self.img1=np.zeros((161,182,3),dtype=np.uint8)
        self.signals=WorkerSignals()
        self.top_process=top_data()
        self.bot_process=bot_data()

    def recvall(self,sock, count):
        buf = b''
        while count:
            if sock:
                newbuf = sock.recv(count)
            if not newbuf: return None
            buf += newbuf
            count -= len(newbuf)
        return buf

    def stream(self,conn):
        length = '0'
        length = (self.recvall(conn,5))
        print ('data len',length)
        if(length[3]==35):
            stringData = self.recvall(conn, int(length[:3]))

        elif(length[4]==35):
            stringData = self.recvall(conn, int(length[:4]))

        else:
            stringData = self.recvall(conn, int(length))
            print('act len',int(length))
            #print('sting 3',stringData)

        data = np.frombuffer(stringData, dtype='uint8')
        decimg = cv2.imdecode(data,1)
        #conn.close()
        return decimg

    def run(self):

        c=1
        print('thread',self.ch,self.test)
        global b1,b2,b3,b4,b5,b6
        if self.test==2:
            for fille in os.listdir(b1[self.ch-1]):
                if fille.endswith('.jpg'):
                    os.remove(b1[self.ch-1]+fille)
            for fille in os.listdir(b2[self.ch-1]):
                if fille.endswith('.jpg'):
                    os.remove(b2[self.ch-1]+fille)
            for fille in os.listdir(b3[self.ch-1]):
                if fille.endswith('.jpg'):
                    os.remove(b3[self.ch-1]+fille)
            for fille in os.listdir(b4[self.ch-1]):
                if fille.endswith('.jpg'):
                    os.remove(b4[self.ch-1]+fille)
            for fille in os.listdir(b5[self.ch-1]):
                if fille.endswith('.jpg'):
                    os.remove(b5[self.ch-1]+fille)
            for fille in os.listdir(b6[self.ch-1]):
                if fille.endswith('.jpg'):
                    os.remove(b6[self.ch-1]+fille)
            for fille in os.listdir(b7[self.ch-1]):
                if fille.endswith('.jpg'):
                    os.remove(b7[self.ch-1]+fille)
        while not stopEvent.is_set():

            img1=self.stream(self.t1)
            d1=convertimg(img1)
            if self.ch>=7:
                self.bot1=self.recvall(self.t2,30)
            if self.ch<=6:
                self.top1=self.recvall(self.t2,40)
            if self.test>0:
                if self.ch<=6:
                    self.top_process.taskvar(self.top1,img1,self.ttype,self.ptype,self.test,self.ch)
                    self.top_process.start()
                    self.top_process.signals.finish.connect(self.sendata,Qt.DirectConnection)
                if self.ch>=7:
                    self.bot_process.taskvar(self.bot1,img1,self.ttype,self.ptype,self.test,self.ch)
                    self.bot_process.start()


            if self.ch==1:
                self.signals.i1.emit(d1)

            if self.ch==2:
                self.signals.i2.emit(d1)

            if self.ch==3:
                self.signals.i3.emit(d1)

            if self.ch==4:
                self.signals.i4.emit(d1)

            if self.ch==5:
                self.signals.i5.emit(d1)

            if self.ch==6:
                self.signals.i6.emit(d1)

            if self.ch==7:
                self.signals.i7.emit(d1)

            if self.ch==8:
                self.signals.i8.emit(d1)

            if self.ch==9:
                self.signals.i9.emit(d1)

            if self.ch==10:
                self.signals.i10.emit(d1)

            if self.ch==11:
                self.signals.i11.emit(d1)

            if self.ch==12:
                self.signals.i12.emit(d1)
            c=c+1
```

There are 12 clients which simultaneously send one image and one string to the server. Can someone tell me why there is a data loss?? is it a race condition or there is error in receiving code.

Comment: Why point out that data is lost? How are you sure it is the client or is it the server? If you want help, explain your real problem clearly and show proof of what you are saying, provide a [MRE] of your clients and server

Answer (score 0):

One way to solve this is to add a mutex.

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import QMutex
```

You put it in your init:

```
self.mutex = QMutex()
```

Then you lock that part of your code that receives the picture:

```
if self.mutex.tryLock():
    # receive picture

self.mutex.unlock()
```

For more info and examples you could check the official documentation of 
[QMutex](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmutex.html)

Let me know if it works!

Comment: Nope. Streaming became slow and data loss is random from each client